# Necessity of an Inductor at CAN Transceiver end

Tags: inductor, embedded, automotive, can

[image: Necessity of L310]

Basically 120 ohm of resistor needs to be connected as terminator resistor at the end of the physical CAN channel.

My question is that here, what is the necessity of an inductor (L310) between CAN transceiver and physical CAN line ?

Comment: It's an EMI filter. There are such parts especially suitable for CAN.

Comment: I'll not repeat its purpose as Andy Aka explained in his answer. You are asking about its necessity. It's necessary if the bus lines are long. If you ask "how much long?", I cannot say an exact number. I was using them while I was designing for Automotive.

Comment: @RohatKılıç yeah the length of bus  would be in few meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the necessity of an inductor (L310) between CAN transceiver
>   and physical CAN line

L310 and the two 220 pF capacitors form a common mode filter so that common mode interference on the line (to the left) is not transferred at the same magnitude to the chip on the right.

If you can provide a data sheet for L310, more information can be provided.